# User inputs N, find all pairs of a and b co-primes where a<N & b<N

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void gcd(){
    int a,b,hcf;
    for (int i = 1; i <=  b; ++i) {
        if (a % i == 0 && b % i ==0) {
            hcf = i;
        }
    }
}
void pirm(){
    int a,b,n,hcf;
for (int a=1;a<n;a++){
    for (int b=1;b<n;b++){
gcd();
if (hcf==1) {
        cout << a << " and " << b << endl;
}
}
}
}
int main(){
    int n,a,b,i,hcf;
cout << "Enter a natural n, less than 100" << endl;
cin >> n;
if (n>=1 && n<100){
pirm();
}
else
    cout << "You didn't enter a natural number" <<endl;
}
```

When I run it and enter a number, it doesn't do anything. The task is as follows: 
User enters a natural N, that is less than 100. Find and output all pairs of co-primes that are < 100.

As you can tell by the code, I'm a complete newb at C++. Just wondering why the program "stops" or where I messed up the code in general. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior. `pirm()` accesses uninitialized local variables `n` and `hcf`. You use local variables as if they were globals, but they aren't. I suggest you read about local and global variables, and about passing parameters to functions, in your favorite C++ textbook.

Comment: This is probably a question better suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I thought code review was for working code. This is not working code.

Comment: @NPras No, not really. This code is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues here.

First, the direct answer to your question: your program never prints because it never executes a print statement. If you enter a natural number, but `hcf` is never equal to 1, you will never print anything.

Now the question becomes why is `hcf` never 1? And that's where we start to run into more issues with your code. The main misunderstanding seems to be about scope. If you declare variables inside a function, they are within the function's "scope" -- the function can use them, and any scope inside the function can use them (e.g. loops and conditionals), but no outer scope can use them. You declare `a`, `b`, and `hcf`several times, but you only ever use them in `gcd()`. Not only is this unnecessary, but critically, these are *different variables*. You change the `hcf` in the scope of `gcd()`, but the `hcf` in `pirm()` is unchanged!

There are many ways to do what you're trying to do. The one that's closest to what you already have is to have `gcd()` take parameters by reference. If you change your declaration of `gcd()` to `void gcd(int a, int b, int &hcf)`, and *do not* redeclare those variables in the first line of the function, then you are able to modify `hcf` in a way that will stick even when the function goes out of scope. You will then need to change your call on line 15 to `gcd(a,b,hcf);`.

Your algorithm could also be improved, though I believe it will still work. If you're interested in a more canonical way to find the gcd, try looking into [Euclid's algorithm](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/the-euclidean-algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

You should learn how to pass arguments to a function. Corrected your code for you, seems to be working:

```
#include <iostream>

void gcd(int &hcf, int a, int b) 
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= b; ++i) 
    {
        if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0) 
        {
            hcf = i;
        }
    }
}

void pirm(int n) 
{
    int hcf;

    for (int a = 1; a<n; a++) 
    {
        for (int b = 1; b<n; b++) 
        {
            gcd(hcf, a, b);
            if (hcf == 1) 
            {
                std::cout << a << " and " << b << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{

    int n;

    std::cout << "Enter a natural n, less than 100" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> n;
    if (n >= 1 && n<100) 
    {
        pirm(n);
    }
    else
        std::cout << "You didn't enter a natural number" << std::endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```